# Suspend Apps Using Package Manager Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-package-managers

How can I suspend all apps on my fully managed device?

I've already tried using `ResolveInfo` and `queryIntentActivity`, but it only suspends some of the basic user apps (camera, gallery, calendar, etc.), and not apps like Spotify, YouTube, Netflix, Play Store, Gmail, etc. Is there a solution to this problem?

Here is the code I've been using to suspend apps except for some allowed ones:

```
private void suspendAllAppsExceptAllowedApps(DevicePolicyManager dpm, ComponentName adminComponent) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<String> exemptPackages = Arrays.asList("com.android.settings", "com.example.MyAppsSuspend", "com.android.contacts", "com.android.phone");
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> packages = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : packages) {
        try {
            String package_name = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (!exemptPackages.contains(package_name)) {
                String[] suspended = dpm.setPackagesSuspended(adminComponent, new String[]{package_name}, true);
                if (suspended != null) {
                    // Log.i("AppSuspend", "Package suspended: " + suspended);
                } else {
                    Log.i("AppSuspend", "Failed to suspend package: " + package_name);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("AppSuspend", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```